# How do I center align two minipages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, sharelatex

I am trying to center align the following two minipages. Or at least set the margin on both sides from the border of the page? I also included the result from the code below.

Something else to note is that I have all the code below already in another `\begin{center}` and am using the `showframe` package.

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}

        SampleText
        \vspace{6cm}

        \large
        \textbf{Title}

        \vspace{0.5cm}

        \vfill

    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}
            \textbf{{Student:}}\\
                Name Lastname\\
                StdNr: 123456\\
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{8cm}
            \textbf{{Supervisors:}}\\
                Name Lastname\\
                Name Lastname\\
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}


        \thispagestyle{empty}

        \clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

[image]
**Edit**: Sorry for not statig my problem clearly enough. I want to move the two minipages as seen in the screenshot above, horizontally until there is an equal space to the edges on both sides. Whilst keeping the formating untouched otherwise.

**Edit**: I edited my screenshot as to what the result should roughly look like:
[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) on this site it is preferred to post full but minimal examples, then others can easily test your code without having to guess parts of it. (3) center in which direction, please clarify

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "center align".

Comment: Maybe you want to use `\centering` inside of those `minipage`s?

Comment: @daleif I have edited my posting with more info. This is sopposed to be a "Titlepage" and is in a titlepage.tex file of its own.

Comment: @JaxTeller please edit your question in such a way that it becomes compilable, meaning it is i complete selfcontained valid LaTeX file you could run through one of the available engines. In the following link you can read how a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) should look like.

Comment: use tabular instead of minipages - they have the width of the enclosed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `tabular` rather than `minipage`. The `showframe` package is just for showing the text block, so to precisely see that the effect is as expected.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}% for debugging

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

SampleText

\vspace{6cm}

{\large\textbf{Title}\\}

\vfill

\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{Student:}\\
    Name Lastname\\
    StdNr: 123456
  \end{tabular}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{Supervisors:}\\
    Name Lastname\\
    Name Lastname
  \end{tabular}\hfill
}

\vspace*{3pt}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I've tried to achieve. Didn't think of using tabular.